# Remove Trailing Zeros from Sharepoint List Lookup Field that is based on a Calculated Field

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, lookup-column

I have two Sharepoint Lists, one of which has a Primary ID field that is a Calculated Field that simply equals the Sharepoint generated ID field. Table 2 has a Lookup field that pulls in this new Primary ID. However, when it pulls in that number, it has ten trailing zeros. The field that is being looked up from Table 1 (and is a calculated field) is a Single Line of Text. Why is the lookup adding zeros to a text field and how do I get rid of them? I tried changing the format of the Calculated Primary ID field to Number and setting the decimal places to zero, however the Lookup no longer functions when I do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the calculated field through `=TEXT(ID,"0")`, which converts a value to text in a specific number format:

[image]

Then lookup it in another list as shown below:

[image]

More information:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/text-function-4b46e545-e612-4c84-ac23-edfa68007945

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much

Comment: Please remember to mark it as answer, It will help others who meet the similar question in this forum.